# Aligning a tikzpicture to linewidth but with labels on the margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I am working on some plots and diagrams, and I would like them to take the full text width (eventually these will be some mix of pgfplots and tikz). However, sometimes some objects are sticking out and I am desperately looking for a way to (i'm not sure) make something with box of main meat of my diagram (and width I control, that's the easy part), but with labels, legends and stuff sticking out, so i have the big thing nicely aligned, and the rest on the margins.
I made a minimal example with a rectangle having label drawn left to it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={12cm, 20cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[1]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,0) rectangle (12, 1);
        \draw(6,0.5) node{Good!};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \blindtext[1]
    
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw(0,0) rectangle (12, 1);
        \draw(6,0.5) node{Not good :(};
        \draw(0,0.5) node[left] {Label:};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \blindtext[1]
    
    \hspace{-1.7cm}\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw(0,0) rectangle (12, 1);
    \draw(6,0.5) node{Good, but manual :(};
    \draw(0,0.5) node[left] {Label:};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with picture showing both the effect i want and effect i get.

[image: example]
How shall I approach that?

Comment: Just use `\draw(0,0.5) node[left,overlay] {Label:};` then it is not taken into account when determining the size of the image

Comment: Thank you for the answer! "overlay" is the keyword that also allowed me to find the suitable section in pgfplots manual (section 4.20) to solve all the rest of my problems